# How do I save a default address programmatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento, magento2

How do I save customer default addresses programmatically in Magento version 2?

I have extended editpost controller for the same but not getting how to save default address (new address and update too).

Answer (score 15):

I found a solution to add customer address programmatically.

```
$addresss = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');
    $address = $addresss->create();
    $address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
    ->setFirstname('Mav')
    ->setLastname('rick')
    ->setCountryId('HR')
    //->setRegionId('1') //state/province, only needed if the country is USA
    ->setPostcode('31000')
    ->setCity('Osijek')
    ->setTelephone('0038511223344')
    ->setFax('0038511223355')
    ->setCompany('GMI')
    ->setStreet('NO:12 Lake View')
    ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
    ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
    ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
    try{
            $address->save();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
            Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: How to set street of two lines?

Comment: For multi-line street address, just add a new line in the string: `$address->setStreet("1234 Example St.\nP.O. Box 12345")`

Comment: Does this update the Customer_entity table as well?
I mean does its new address id gets saved against the getDefaultShippingAddress() ?
If not , how to save the customer object as well?

Comment: Code is working fine, thanks